# trying to Change color of background throught clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have tried to give body<> a class with same name .. so that use it later to change the color of background when button is clicked .. i do not know if it from the syntax right .., any suggustions

```
<script>
    function ChangeColor()
    {
        var ChangeColor = document.getElementsByClassName("body");
        ChangeColor.style.background-color = "grey";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: also should be `backgroundColor`

Comment: why did you put this size of array here ? .. i tried that but it does not work ..

Comment: try my code. or maybe sholud be `getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   function ChangeColor(){
      var ChangeColor = document.getElementsByClassName("body")[0];
      ChangeColor.style.backgroundColor = "grey"; 
    }
```

Comment: that was new to me with size of array ..i did not know that getElementsByClassName give collection back .. that why should choose thr first element  :) .. thanks that was helpfull

Comment: you're welcome. please accept the my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClass name returns an array, you choose the first item

```
function changeColor(){ 
  var ChangeColor = document.getElementsByClassName("body")[0]; 
  ChangeColor.style.backgroundColor = "grey"; 
}
```

then call the function

```
 changeColor();
```

that should work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes

First you need to pass index when using `document.getElementsByClassName` since it is a collection.  Second for inline styling using javascript rename `background-color` to `backgroundColor`

```js
function changeColor() {
  var changeColor = document.getElementsByClassName("body")[0];
  changeColor.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
}

changeColor()
```

```html
<body class='body'>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns a array.

So you should do like :

```
ChangeColor[0].style.background-color = "grey"
```

I believe you are not using any framework that could make that.
In that case i would suggest to add a id to the element and use getElementById.
In that case it will return a single element